# Issue with loading data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to load the content of a json file into an array. Instead of using the callback function to ensure file is loaded before I use it, I coded it like this:

```
var f_file_loaded = false;
var data = null;

$.getJSON('transformation.json', function(dt){
    f_file_loaded = true;
    data = dt;
});

while(!f_file_loaded){
    // Loop until file is loaded
}

console.log('data loaded', data);
```

This however, blocks the browser and the f_file_loaded doesn't seem to go true any time. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Welcome to the world of async calls

Comment: if you want to do a sync call to server, check out async property of $.ajax on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

`while(!f_file_loaded){` doesn't work as you expect...it just creates an infinite loop.

You need to use the `promise()` interface.

```
$.when($.getJSON()).done(function() {
    // file is loaded, execute whatever code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because $.getJSON is an async call.

You should do something along these lines:

```
function data_loaded(data) {
    console.log('data loaded', data);
}

$.getJSON('transformation.json', function(dt){
    data_loaded(dt);
});
```

Comment: in that case, why not just pass data_loaded to getJSON? (why the wrap?)

Comment: It's just an example, that function could be defined elsewhere and be more complex

Comment: Ok. But my question is why my code doesn't work? I know the call is async but at some point file is finally loaded and f_file_load is true , while the loop has already been started

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do sync not async call, then use this

your code above

```
$.ajax("transformation.json", {
dataType:'json',
async:false,
success:function(dt) {
data = dt;
}
});
```

your code below will continue execution after data is downloaded